# Исходный код в tarball и код в репозитории различаются. Почему?

Tags: java, git, ivy

Разбираясь с apache-ivy 2.4.0, обнаружил, что код, в опубликованном, source-tarball и код в репозитории различаются.
Почему код не одинаковый? Зачем так сделано для Java проекта? Возможно, это некоторый общий шаблон или практика - подскажите.

Для С++ проекта я мог бы придумать причину. Например, можно в source-tarball упаковать код подготовленный для платформозависимой копмиляции, а всё что платформонезависимо предварительно сгенерировать\скомпилировать.
Но зачем это нужно для Java?

Ссылки на репозиторий и source-tarball apache-ivy 2.4.0 есть здесь: https://ant.apache.org/ivy/download.cgi

PS. (дать две различных ссылки и создать метку apache-ivy у меня не хватает репутации)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В тарболле вы скачиваете исходники релиза 2.4.0.

Из репозитория вы выкачиваете текущую версию исходного кода. Если посмотреть [историю коммитов](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=ant-ivy.git;a=log) можно увидеть, что релизу 2.4.0 соответствует коммит [c8150bddf2fc99e5467c203d6a28758a0820a237](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=ant-ivy.git;a=commit;h=c8150bddf2fc99e5467c203d6a28758a0820a237) от 26 декабря 2014. С тех пор досыпали 24 коммита. Отсюда и разница.

Если вы сделаете `git checkout` на упомянутый коммит, то найдете то же , что и в тарболле.

---

Если вас смущает отсутствие в архиве некоторых файлов и директорий (.settings, .checkstyle и т.п.) - очевидно, что разработчики "чистят" исходники перед выкатыванием в тарболл: убирают файлы проекта, необходимые только команде на время разработки, но не нужные конечному пользователю для сборки проекта.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ! Не совсем понял, как Вы нашли этот комит.  Я искал по тэгу и нашёл этот: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=ant-ivy.git;a=tag;h=refs/tags/2.4.0

Comment: Просто посмотрел историю коммитов.

Comment: Да, меня смущает отсутствие в tarball'e некоторых файлов. Если есть практика вычищать всё, что не нужно для сборки, то зачем там осталась документация? Зачем tarball нужен пользователю, если есть собранная версия? IMHO, если tarball для программиста, то там должны быть все файлы.

Comment: Содержание комита c8150bddf2fc99e5467c203d6a28758a0820a237 тоже отличается от содержания tarball.   Или я не правильно пользуюсь git?

Comment: Еще раз, в репе - исходники, с которыми работает команда разработчиков. Там может лежать что угодно, что требуется в данный момент команде, хоть рецепты кофейных коктейлей. Тарболл - это дистрибутив исходников. В нем все, что нужно для сборки и развертывания приложения у потребителя (включая документацию).

Comment: Nofate, спасибо! Про tarball я понял, ответ принят.. Дополнительный вопрос: конкретно в ivy 2.4.0 исходные коды отличаются, почему? Может быть это связано с шаблонами Java?

Comment: Можно пример на конкретном файле?

Comment: Всё разобрался. Исходный код в tarball совпадает с исходым кодом в репе по метке 2.4.0 (комит 0b9db35ee7a94a719e538b04122b86cb997f3a17). Не совпадает только документация и дополнительные файлы (например для настройки IDE). Ещё раз спасибо, вопрос можно закрывать